# String splitting advice for speed in C

Tags: c, string, csv, memcpy

I have an array of chars(uint8_t) that has a size of 3060. This comes from reading a CSV file that each line has 51 bytes of data for. I want this to be split up so I can get this data 51 bytes at a time. So what I want is 0-51 then 52-102 etc.

What i intend to do with this is then send this data out via a bluetooth gatt connection I have working.
Is it possible to memcpy part of this array for instance:

`memcpy(my3060_data[0-50],data_to_send_1,sizeof(data_to_send_1));`

Then loop the value upto 3060?

Therefore, I want this process to be quick any advice?

Comment: `0-51` would be `52` bytes: `array[0] - array[51]`.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, I have amended it in the question,

Comment: Better to pass the address around than copy the 51 bytes.

Comment: 3060 is not a lot - beware of premature optimizations.

Comment: Can you just read the file, line by line and send that over GATT?

Comment: You can think of using strtok() function to split the string and then send it?

Comment: "a CSV file that each line has 51 bytes of data" --> Is that _line_ 50 characters and then a `'\n'`, or 51 characters and then a `'\n'`, or something else?

Comment: its 50 characters with a \n. I can send it line by line and, that Is what I am trying to do. This is because I dont want to call a SD card read function each time I want to read a single line. Therefore, I want to read a bunch of lines then send them out, then read a bunch more. Otherwise I will destroy the SD card quickly overtime with reading soo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want this process to be quick any advice?

Read the file with 1 `fread()`.  The biggest place to save time is with an efficient I/O operation.

This is before OP's "I have an array of `chars(uint8_t)` that has a size of 3060", but it will be more useful to speed that up than minor code tweaks in subsequent code.

```
#define DATA_SIZE 3060
uint8_t data[DATA_SIZE+1];  // One more to detect too large a file.
if (DATA_SIZE == fread(data, 1, sizeof data, CSV_file)) {
  // Success
} else {
  // Oops
}
```

---

OP's `memcpy()` is certainly amiss.

```
// Bad
// memcpy(my3060_data[0-50],data_to_send_1,sizeof(data_to_send_1));

// More like
#define LINE_SIZE 51
for (int index = 0; index < DATA_SIZE; index += LINE_SIZE) {

  uint8_t data_to_send_1[LINE_SIZE];
  memcpy(data_to_send_1, &my3060_data[index], LINE_SIZE);
  send_it(data_to_send_1, LINE_SIZE);

  // OR skip the copy

  send_it(&my3060_data[index], LINE_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Just to check the &my3060_data[index] is the start location in memory for the "line size" that has been passed to? So starting at 0 then sending 51 bytes of data, then the next 51 untill it has reached the data size?

Comment: @ThomasMorris Yes.  Other forms: `&(my3060_data[index])`, `my3060_data + index`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop would simplify the process.  For example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t buffer[52], chunkSize, data[3060];
    uint16_t processed = 0;

    while(processed < sizeof(data))
    {
        if((processed + sizeof(buffer)) < sizeof(data))
            chunkSize = sizeof(buffer);
        else
            chunkSize = sizeof(data) - processed;

        printf("%u, ", chunkSize);

        memcpy(buffer, data + processed, chunkSize);
        processed += chunkSize;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This producing the following:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 44,
```

Notice the last chunk is 44 bytes.

What you do with buffer is up to you.

Comment: This seems good but, I don't want to print the chunck size I want to effectively print the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the CSV file line by line then you could do something like:

```
char buffer[100];
FILE *fptr;
if ((fptr = fopen("file_to_open.csv", "r")) = NULL) 
{
    printf("Error! opening file");
    // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
    exit(1);
}


while(fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", buffer)!=EOF)
{
//process buffer
}
fclose(fptr);
```